# For Grails, Optimizing Controller to Services invocation in relation to sharing data and accessing the database

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I have a set of domains like this:

```
    class Unit {
    String unitName
    Long latitude
    Long longitude
    Template template
    static belongsTo = [Template]
}
class Template {
    String templateName
    static hasMany = [features: Feature,
                      systems: Unit]
}
class Feature {
    String featureName
    static hasMany = [templates: Template, components: Component]
    static belongsTo = [Template]       
}
class Component {
    String componentName
    static hasMany = [fileParts: FilePart,
    listDefinitions: ListDefinition,
                      settings: Setting,
                      features: Feature]    
    static belongsTo = [Feature]
}
class Setting {
    String settingName
    SettingTypeEnum settingTypeEnum
    String settingValue
    static hasMany = [components: Component]
    static belongsTo = [Component]
} // more tables not shown.
```

That create a MySQL structure like this:
[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

In a Service method, given the Unit Id, I collect all of the related values I need into a map...

```
    class UnitService {
boolean transactional = false
def serviceGatherAllSystem(Long sysid) {        
def sys = Unit.get(sysid)       
    def builder = [
    sys.collect{
        [
        systemName: sys.unitName,
        templateName: sys.template.templateName,
        features: sys.template.features.collect{ featureItem ->
            [
            featureName: featureItem.featureName,
            components: featureItem.components.collect{ comp ->                         [
                compName: comp.name,
                    settings: comp.settings.collect{ sets ->                            [
                    settingName: sets.name,
                    settingType: sets.settingTypeEnum.value,
                    settingValue: sets.value                     
                    ]
                    },//settings
                    files: comp.fileParts.collect{ files->
                    [
                    fileName: files.name,
                    fileType: files.filePartTypeEnum.value,
                    fileValue: files.value
                    ]
                    },//files
                    listsDef: comp.listDefinitions.collect{ list->
                    [
                    listID: list.id,
                    listName: list.listDefinitionName,
                    listDisplayName: list.listDisplayName,                              listLevelCount: list.levelCount
                    ]                               
                    }
                ]                               
                }//components                                           
            ]
            }//features         
        ]
        }//sys.collect  
    ]//def builder      
    return builder
}//serviceGatherSytem
```

Once I have done that DB call and retrieved those values, I’d like to use them for the duration of the request, and just “dive” into the resulting Map to obtain specific details. I think that I can accomplish this at the Controller level by putting this into the Controller.

```
def unitService //the UnitService.groovy class
def unitDetails 
def index() {   
    longId = (params.unitId).toLong()       
    unitDetails = unitService.serviceGatherAllSystem(longId)
}
```

Then, at any time, I can interrogate unitDetails in other methods of the Controller and have the results of serviceGatherAllSystem() without incurring another DB fetch. 
However, I’d love to push a bunch of the logic and coding for fetching data out of the results of serviceGatherAllSystem() down into UnitService.groovy and NOT code it in the Controller to keep the controller thin and use it elsewhere.

My assumption is that if I define another method (below) like serviceJsonSettings() inside UnitServices.groovy that invokes serviceGatherAllSystem(), then I am going to cause re-querying the DB, right?

Should I create another method inside UnitServices.groovy showDetails() that takes as a parameter the unitDetails and call it from the Controller – that way I invoke serviceGatherAllSystem() once on the request and just pass the results around to interrogate?

Or is there a Groovy way for me to save off the result at the request level, or “save” them in UnitService.groovy class and use them in a different method inside UnitService.groovy again?

```
    class UnitService{

def serviceGatherAllSystem(Long sysid) {
    ...
}

//invoke serviceGatherAllSystem() causes another DB fetch, right???
def serviceJsonSettings(long id){

        String jsons = ""

        def result = serviceGatherAllSystem(id)

        result.features.components.settings.each(){ a ->
            a.each() { b ->
                b.each() {c ->
                    c.each(){d ->
                        d.each(){                           
                            if (it.settingsType == SettingTypeEnum.JSON.value){jsons = jsons + it.settingValue + ", "}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        return jsons.substring(0, jsons.length() - 2)       
    }

//pass results of serviceGatherAllSystem() 
def serviceJsonSettings(Map unitDetails){

        String jsons = ""       

        unitDetails.features.components.settings.each(){ a ->
            a.each() { b ->
                b.each() {c ->
                    c.each(){d ->
                        d.each(){                           
                            if (it.settingsType == SettingTypeEnum.JSON.value){jsons = jsons + it.settingValue + ", "}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        return jsons.substring(0, jsons.length() - 2)       
    }
 ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into doing either an HQL query with eager fetching or a criteria query with the same. Once you do so, you can boil this down to one underlying query. While you could store the (detached) result in the service and re-serve it to avoid subsequent queries, you may find that the one query may be fast enough or that second-level caching already provides what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand the point of `unitService.serviceGatherAllSystem`. Why bother transforming all the domain objects into a hierarchy of nested maps, when you could presumably just navigate the domain class hierarchy instead, e.g. replace this

```
def index() {   
  longId = (params.unitId).toLong()       
  unitDetails = unitService.serviceGatherAllSystem(longId)
}
```

with this

```
def index() {        
  Unit unit = Unit.get(params.unitId)
}
```

Although you could store the `Unit` in one of the controller's fields and access it from there (because a separate instance of the controller class is created for each request), I dislike this approach and never use it myself. One reason I dislike this approach is that it leads to code that is hard to read. For example, consider this controller

```
class MyController {

  private Foo foo
  private Bar bar
  private Unit unit

  def index() {        
    unit = Unit.get(params.unitId)
    foo = Foo.get(params.fooId)
    bar = Unit.get(params.barId)
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
  }

  private doSomething() {
    //implementation omitted
  }

  private doSomethingElse() {
    //implementation omitted
  }
}
```

There's no easy way to see which of the fields `foo`, `bar`, `unit` are being used by `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`, whereas if you write the code like this instead

```
class MyController {

  def index() {        
    Unit unit = Unit.get(params.unitId)
    Foo foo = Foo.get(params.fooId)
    Bar bar = Unit.get(params.barId)
    doSomething(unit)
    doSomethingElse(foo, bar)
  }

  private doSomething(Unit unit) {
    //implementation omitted
  }

  private doSomethingElse(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    //implementation omitted
  }
}
```

You only need to look at the parameter list of `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` to see what objects they use. In general it's best to avoid methods that have "side effects" if possible.

In my example above, the business logic is being performed by private methods of the controller, but it's preferable to move business logic into service methods instead. One reason for this is that services can be re-used across the application (they can be called from any controller, taglib, domain class, etc.), and also because services are transactional by default.

### Update

Further to your comments below, I now understand that the conversion of the domain object hierarchy to nested maps is an attempt to load all the data in one shot.

However, assuming the relationships between your domain classes are lazy (the default), then the nested maps will not be constructed from a single query - each time you access an association a separate query will be issued. Turn on SQL logging to confirm this. The only way to get all the data you need via a single query is to make the associations between the domain classes eager. You can either make these associations eager on a per-query basis or for all queries. If you want the latter, then you configure the eager associations in the domain classes themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Don.  If I grab the Unit and then in each place where I need to access the related tables traverse into while assembling the Response to the Request, then am I causing reads to the DB multiple times?  The large map I created is one "hit" to the DB and then I can look at the map later as I assemble the rest of the response.  My thought was that this would diminish the hits to the DB and improve performance. Which is the case?